# Clone and run react native projects from GitHub

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to build and run react native application in my phone. I tried with [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) and it's working fine. I do the following to run

1. `cd AwesomeProject`
2. `react-native start`
3. Open a new tab in terminal
4. `curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"`
5. `react-native run-android`

and it runs in my android phone.

Now I am trying to run a [project from GitHub](https://github.com/h87kg/NavigatorDemo), I did the following

1. `git clone https://github.com/h87kg/NavigatorDemo.git`
2. `cd NavigatorDemo`
3. `react-native start`

I get `Command 'start' unrecognized. Did you mean to run this inside a react-native project?` error. What should I do to run this project ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

After installing dependencies `npm install` I am able to run the server.
Now when I try to run `react-native run-android` I get the following error

```
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Could not install the app on the device, see the error above.
```

Comment: Not an answer but I really never used `start` command. After cd into project directory  i just do react-native run-android or run-ios  :S . Oh yeah and if its other's project normally you have to `npm install` the dependencies first too.

Comment: yes we don't need to run `start` if it starts automatically, yes i have updated the question

Comment: @Saahityan  , not sure what its called but close any "other" existing react packager terminal before running new project.

Comment: @cjmling, how do I stop, what is the command or u mean `ctrl+c`

Comment: I normally just simply close the GUI screen.

Answer (score 22):

Did you install **node modules**? try `npm install`

1. `git clone https://github.com/h87kg/NavigatorDemo.git`
2. `cd NavigatorDemo`
3. `npm install`
4. `react-native start`

Comment: Yes thanks, that starts the server. But still I couldn't run the project I get `Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that the **gradlew** file in the android folder isn't executable anymore because you cloned it from a git repo.

Basically, when you do `react-native run-android`,  It does a lot of thing which includs running commands for you such as `cd android && ./gradlew installDebug`. right there, it tries to execute the gradlew, but can't, cause the file isn't executable. which is why you get that error.

just `cd` into the **android** folder, and do `chmod +x gradlew`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get it, why npx doesn't fix the permission issue

Comment: oh this is a good note.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, this is how I got it working and sharing it with others who are facing the same problem

1. Create a folder called `assets` inside `android/app/src/main/`
2. Copied `gradle` folder inside `android/` from my existing working project `AwesomeProject`
3. `(cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)`
4. `curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"`
5. `react-native run-android`

These are the exact steps I followed, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy gradle folder inside android/ from my existing working project root
2. Go to android directory and run this: ./gradlew installDebug
3. Now copy your gradle folder back to the original location.

This is the solution that worked for me. Do not forget to close the node server during the process.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-native-fs --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

This will fix your issue